# Mongo converting ISO date into weird string

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I converted this date format

> "date" : "2016-02-22 13:52:23"

using this code

```
db.gmastats.find({date: {$not: {$type: 9}}}).forEach(function(doc) {doc.date = new Date(doc.date); db.gmastats.save(doc);})
```

And Mongo gave me this:

```
 ISODate("-292275055-05-16T16:47:03.192Z")
```

What do I do to get this into something that is a real date?

Answer (score 1):

The date string is not valid, but with a small conversion it is. Basically you just need to a `"T"` between the "date" part and the "time" part, then `new Date()` will work it out just fine.

```
 db.gmastats.find({ "date": { "$type": 2 } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.date = new Date(doc.date.split(" ").join("T")); 
    db.gmastats.save(doc);
 })
```

Also noting that it's not safe to just look for things that are not a BSON Date. You should be looking **only** at "string" data when you are acting on a "string".

But really you "should" be doing this with "Bulk" operations:

```
 var ops = [];
 db.gmastats.find({ "date": { "$type": 2 } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    ops.push({ "updateOne": { 
        "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
        "update": { "$set": { "date": new Date(doc.date.split(" ").join("T")) } }
    }});

    if ( ops.length == 1000 ) {
       db.gmastats.bulk_write(ops);
       ops = []
    }
 })

 if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
     db.gmastats.bulk_write(ops);
 }
```

Which will go much faster and also safely **"only"** updates the `"date"` property of the data without affecting other concurrent write operations.